# C# Chart crashes if there is a big Y-value

Tags: c#

I read a bunch of values from a file and then show the data in a chart. But my chart crashes if there is a really big Y-value. Is there a bug in the chart object?

Example code to illustrate the problem:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(0);
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(1);
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(3);
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(1);
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(9);
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(5);
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddY(3.15486e+29); // This big value makes the chart crash
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Is this a known bug?

Comment: since big value is pointless and unable to show, just **replace with reasonable big value** before add to chart.

Comment: Try using a Log Y axis scale. I'd say it's by design that this doesn't work with a standard Line Chart.

Comment: But it is crazy that 3.15486e+28 works but not 3.15486e+29 :-/

Comment: In my VS2017 the error acutally is 'Value too big or small for decimal'.

Comment: A Log y-axis doesn't help either. But, as Lei wrote, the value makes little sense in a graphical chart..

Answer (score -1):

Isn't the AddY property an Int, and The value that your passing in is exceeding this? You haven't shown the error but I suspect that your getting something like: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32".

Comment: No and no. It is a __double__ and the error is 'value too big or small for __decimal__'

Comment: [link] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456331(v=vs.110).aspx) Isn't this the correct namespace?

Comment: You are confusing the paramter with the return type.

Answer (score -1):

One cannot plot infinity with any chart so like trying to plot large value like 3.15486e+29 your chart application is getting crash. There are two ways to handle such issues:

1. Scale and filter inputs into range being plotted and acceptable to chart in question say to [Ymin to Ymax] and any data outside this to be shown as **invalid**
2. Use logarithmic graphs if data scaling varies a lot.

Answer (score -1):

So the problem is that charts uses decimal internally. So when I add an Y value of 3.15486e+29 it does not fit into the decimal type range.

Problem solved (at least why the chart bugs out).

:-)

Comment: Neither to decimal.. All values (including e.g. DataTimes) are internally converted to double.